# Can Clang accept LLVM IR or bitcode via pipe?

Tags: clang, llvm-ir

Clang can accept source files through a pipe if a language is specified with the `-x` flag.

```
cat hello_world.c | clang -x c -o hello_world
```

Clang can also compile LLVM IR and bitcode to object files

```
clang hello_world.c -S -emit-llvm && clang -o hello_world hello_world.ll
```

I want to compile LLVM IR or bitcode passed via a pipe.  However, I can't find any documentation on exactly what parameters the `-x` option accepts.  I can use `c`, `c++`, but clang doesn't recognize `llvm` or `bitcode`.

What can I give to `-x` so Clang will accept IR or bitcode?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The language flag you're looking for is `ir`. For example:

```
clang hello_world.c -S -emit-llvm -o - | clang -x ir -o hello_world -
```

works for me (clang version 3.5, trunk 200156).

Comment: Is this documented anywhere?